# Workbox 6: ReferenceError: swDest is not defined

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker, workbox

Getting ReferenceError: swDest is not defined when trying to run Workbox 6.

In my sw_build.js file I have that I call with node sw_build.js in my package.json file...

[image]

In the console I see this as the output:

[image]

It appears as though the files get created?, I just don't understand why I'm getting the odd error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `swDest` reference is in line 16, and `swDest` is not defined. That's why the file is created but error occurs. I think you copied the example code without modification on this line.

Comment: Thanks! That did it. I was pulling together two sources and overlooked that.

Comment: @AdamYoungers better set up a linter to avoid mistakes :)

Comment: Yeah, good call. I have it setup as part of my standard build, but didn't consider it for my sw build.